# Date and time based json element using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a json response like this :

```
{
 "NO_INSPECTION": "55",
 "NO_SURAT": "00055",
 "DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION": "2015-12-21 03:08:24"
}
```

How can I convert the data in `"DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION"` Into date and time. Date should be `dd-mm-yyy` format and time should be in `HH:mm` format. (A sample value of `DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION` is `2015-12-21 03:08:24`)

I have tried `new Date(response.DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION);` but no success. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript Date.parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has a fixed date format and you can change it, thus the `Date` object won't help you this time. As I see it, you want to split that date, so it's pretty easy if you provide it in this format "dd-mm-yyy HH:mm":

```
response.DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION = response.DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION.split(" "); // date and time are separated by an space
var date = response.DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION[0];
var time = response.DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION[1];
```

BTW, if you want to parse a date in a specified format, why don't you use any library for that? Many of them are almost as reliable and fast as native methods. Give them a try ;)

You could also format the date, so it fits the JS specs but, why reinvent the wheel? Libraries will do this for you and you'll get optimal cross-browser results!

I've googled "javascript date parsing library" and this is what I've found:

http://momentjs.com/ <--- I think that's what you're looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Without the use of other libraries and assuming the output will always be zero-padded and the same length, I would do this:

```
var response = {
  DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION: "2015-12-21 03:08:24"
}

var raw = response.DATE_OF_DESCRIPTION;

var datePart = raw.split(' ')[0];
var timePart = raw.split(' ')[1];

var year = datePart.substring(0, 4);
var month = datePart.substring(5, 7);
var day = datePart.substring(8, 10);

var hours = timePart.substring(0, 2);
var minutes = timePart.substring(3, 5);

// NOTE: Month is 0 indexed
var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day);
var dateTime = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hours, minutes);

console.log(date);
console.log(dateTime);
```

This gives the output

```
Mon Dec 21 2015 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (E. Australia Standard Time)
Mon Dec 21 2015 03:08:00 GMT+1000 (E. Australia Standard Time)
(I'm from Australia, so your timezone will vary)
```